# How browsers decide which content is HTML

Tags: html, browser, http-headers

I used to believe that CONTENT-TYPE header of a HTML page tells the browser that the contents are html or not. I have a proxy coded where I was checking content-type has text/html to decide if its HTML or not.

This works fine until I found a URL:

http://www.movingcenter.com/mc.dll?page=home

This URLs response headers are:

> ```
> Connection    close
> Date  Tue, 19 Apr 2011 17:32:35 GMT
> Server    Microsoft-IIS/6.0
> X-Powered-By  ASP.NET
> ```

How can I effectively decide if the page is HTML or not. In this case I know it is.

Thanks
Sparsh Gupta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any HTTP/1.1 message containing an entity-body SHOULD include a Content-Type header field defining the media type of that body. If and only if the media type is not given by a Content-Type field, the recipient MAY attempt to guess the media type via inspection of its content and/or the name extension(s) of the URI used to identify the resource. If the media type remains unknown, the recipient SHOULD treat it as type "application/octet-stream".

— http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html#sec7.2.1

So, you could inspect the start of the message body and see if you can spot a doctype or any HTML tags in it.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers should use the Content-Type property to determine the MIME type of the document and servers should always send one.  However, the answer is that it depends on the browser.  Internet Explorer, for example, has a set of rules ("content sniffing") for determining the content type.  [This is a great summary article](http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/ArticleContentSniffing).  While I feel strange suggesting that you do something like IE, you *could* use similar techniques to detect the content type.